# multiple assignments of objects to variable under ARC

Tags: ios

There's a point of memory management I'm not 100% clear on, suppose there is the following code:

```
{
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = [[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

Does this cause a memory leak of the first allocation? If not why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, BJ is correct, but the generated code is slightly different. It goes something like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];

// Oh, we're changing what `string` points to. Gotta release the old value.
NSString *tmpString = string;
string = [[NSString alloc] init];
[tmpString release];
[string release]; // string goes out of scope at this point in your code
```

This order of operation is usually not that critical (and if you care *too* much about it, you are probably coding incorrectly). But understanding it explains why the objects are destroyed exactly when they are.

Answer (score 2):

Under ARC, this does not leak memory. This is because any time a strong object pointer is changed, the compiler automatically sends a `release` to the old object. Local variables, like `NSString *string`, are strong by default.

So your code above gets compiled to something more like this:

```
{
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];

// Oh, we're changing what `string` points to. Gotta release the old value.
[string release];
string = [[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Does ARC releases it immediately or just put into the main autoreleasepool?

Comment: It releases it immediately, as soon as it determines the old value is not used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not cause a leak. ARC will release the first string before it sets the second string. This is the truly amazing power of ARC!

Comment: Does ARC releases it immediately or just put into the main autoreleasepool?